# Can a preheader show preheader text only?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email

When I add this preheader in Marketing Cloud:
*Only a click away*
and test send my mail to my mailbox, my preheader will look like this:
*Only a click away Online Version Design Catalogue Find a store etc etc.*

So the preheader actually becomes a mix of my preheader and the first available texts in my header element in the email.

**Can I in anyway set up my preheader to show preheader text only?**

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally the email clients show all "text" that they find in the emails up to N# number of characters as an abstract of the email content.

A possible workaround is to add HTML whitespaces (`&nbsp;&zwnj;`= " ‌") after the preheader:

```
<div style="display:none; white-space:nowrap; font:15px courier; color:#ffffff;">
&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;
&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;
&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;
</div>
```

You can do this in 2 ways:

1. (suggested) edit your template/email HTML in the "code view" and place the code above in the `<body>` after `<custom type="header" />`
2. Add to your email a "snippet block" plance it like first element in the email and then paste the code above in the block.

**Remember** that each (non markup) text presente before the code above will be displayed as preheader also if you have "hide" with the HTML CSS/Style.

**Refernce:**
Remove text in preheade

- https://taxiforemail.com/code/snippets/hidden-preheader/
- https://litmus.com/blog/the-little-known-preview-text-hack-you-may-want-to-use-in-every-email

Hide elements in email

- https://litmus.com/blog/gmail-now-supports-display-none-what-it-means-for-your-email-designs

Simone

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a dynamic preheader, set in a ampscript variable, you can use this code snippet I have built to add whitespaces, in order to avoid showing actual email content in the preheader:

```ampscript
IF _messagecontext == 'SEND' THEN
    SET @preheaderLength = length(@preheader)
    SET @maxLength = 120
    SET @spaceFill = subtract(@maxLength, @preheaderLength) 
    FOR @counter = 1 to @spaceFill do 
        SET @preheader = CONCAT(@preheader,'&#847;&zwnj;&nbsp;') 
    NEXT 
ENDIF
```

The whitespace characters and the length are derived from [this Litmus article](https://www.litmus.com/blog/the-little-known-preview-text-hack-you-may-want-to-use-in-every-email/).

Comment: Thank you Lukas :)